# javascript loop through svg animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am having some issues with looping SVG animations.

I figured out how to animate paths, but the problem is that I want them disappear when they are drawn and after a short delay of time show different two ones. I need those two operations to be looped as well.

www.jsfiddle.net/8zneofyw/

Thanks

Comment: I see from your fiddle that you know svg pretty wel, but i cant figure out what operations you want looped and what needs to disapear when they are drawn. Please edit your qustion with a better explenation.

Comment: @Persijn Procedural description:

1 step. Draw two paths
2nd step. Make them disappear
3rd step. Draw different two ones
4th step. Make them dissapear
5th step. Go to 1st step

Answer (score 2):

**Challange accepted**

This is how i solved it:

- Animations run for 10s.
- Each path has a line and an equally long whitespace `stroke-dasharray: 160, 160;`

So this creates an empty line that gets drawn.

But with that all four paths are created at the same time and we want to draw two and two lines.
So we need an delay of 5 second between the first two paths and the second two:

- Add white space after the path to fill half the animation: `stroke-dasharray: 160, 160, 0, 320;`
- Now we just need to start the animations at the right time: `stroke-dashoffset: 160;` for the first two. and `stroke-dashoffset: 320` for the last two.

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 2;
}
#one {
  stroke-dasharray: 160, 160, 0, 320;
  stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  animation: magic 10s linear infinite;
}
#two {
  stroke-dasharray: 160, 160, 0, 320;
  stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  animation: magic 10s linear infinite;
}
#tree {
  stroke-dasharray: 165, 165, 0, 330;
  stroke-dashoffset: 330;
  animation: moremagic 10s linear infinite;
}
#four {
  stroke-dasharray: 165, 165, 0, 330;
  stroke-dashoffset: 330;
  animation: moremagic 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes magic {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50.01% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -160;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -160;
  }
}
@keyframes moremagic {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <circle cx="25" cy="50" r="10" fill="none" stroke="tomato" />
  <circle cx="175" cy="50" r="10" fill="none" stroke="pink" />
  <path id="one" d="m25,50, 150,0" fill="none" stroke="green" />
  <path id="two" d="m25,50, 75,20 75,-20 " fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  <path id="tree" d="m25,50, 75,-20 75,20 " fill="none" stroke="firebrick" />
  <path id="four" d="m25,50, 75,-30 75,30 " fill="none" stroke="aqua" />
</svg>
```